# subquery returns more than 1 row for insert query even though it doesn't have any sub query

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

This question has been posted many times,
but there is a difference compared to the issue I am facing and the issues what others are facing.

Please note the I am executing a query as follows

```
INSERT INTO subcategory (category_categoryID, login_UserName, subcategoryTitle) 
VALUES (25, 'xyz', 'sub1')
```

I am getting following error

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

Interesting thing here is , my above query doesn't include any sub query 
also this error will come only for some of the values 
that is , this error occur for category_categoryID 25 , not for any other values in db .
my category table has more than 30 values

How sql throw an exception for this query ? even though it doesn't have any subquery ?
Or Am I misunderstood the concept?

[image: My database schema]

Comment: Is the Category and subcategory table have any foreign key??

Comment: Do you have triggers on the subcategory table?

Comment: @Sadanand  - I hope subcategory.category_categoryID is a foreign key. So check whether categoryID 25 exists in category table and by any worst chance there isn't more than 1 row of it.

Comment: @smn_onrocks yes category table has user name as foreign key and sub category table has user name and categoryid as foreign key

Comment: @Jens Category table has an entry with categoryId 25, but it is not inserting into subcategory which doesn't has any entry with value 25.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt yes I has a trigger which updates priority value of category when a subcategory is created for that category
Trigger is like this ->  update category set priority = 5 WHERE categoryID = new.category_categoryID;

Comment: @Sharmi you c in the category table the `categoryID` field is marked as primary key and auto increment so there could be no chance of being the value duplicate

Answer (score 1):

May be the problem is not your `category_categoryID` I think if you check your data you will find in `login_UserName` field more than 1 data is present with the value `'xyz'` as the field  `login_UserName` is not conceder as primary key or unique key so please check your data.